# How to specify a Take value with TableClient.QueryAsync

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm updating my project to use `Azure.Data.Tables` 12.6.1, and I can't figure out where to specify a `Take` value to limit the number of entities returned from a query.

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
var limit = 150;
var results = table.QueryAsync<T>(limit);
await foreach (var page in results.AsPages().ConfigureAwait(false)) {
    // Regardless of how the server pages the results, 
    // only the top [limit] items are returned.
}
```

In the old API, you could set a `Take` property on the query object. How do I do this in the new API?

Comment: Does the `MaxPerPage` parameter help you?

Comment: @Skin I don't think that does exactly what I want. If you know the results you want will be on the first page, then yes, it does. But let's say that the server is sending 100 entities per page and you want 120. Saying "120 max per page, please" doesn't change anything. The server still sends 100 per page and you needlessly retrieve 80 entities (because you have to retrieve two pages to get the 120 you need). I just want to say: regardless of the number of pages, give me 120, total. Or if I could say how many I want, max, in the NEXT page, that would be okay too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Skin points out, the current SDK does not expose an explicit API for `Take`, but that was an intentional decision to ensure that it is clearer to developers what is really happening from the service perspective.

The old SDK supported a full `IQueryable` API, which made it easy to create very expensive queries that performed filtering client side after fetching the whole table from the service.

Although `Take` doesn't have the same problems as other Linq methods, the service doesn't really support it. It can only limit the number of results for a paged result (which is capped at 1000 by the service).

While I agree it is not as simple as a Take API, the current API makes it fairly straightforward to implement the equivalent functionality, while not hiding the fact that you may actually fetch more than your Take limit from the service.

[This sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample4QueryEntities.md#query-entities-with-maxperpage) demonstrates how to iterate through the pages with a max items per page set.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Christopher. I have two questions. This page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities) shows that $top is a supported parameter, allowing you to limit the number of entities fetched. Isn't that what Take was utilizing?

Comment: And secondly, the same link shows that you are not guaranteed to get the full 1000 possible entities per page if the result set crosses a partition boundary. So let's say I have 500 entities spread across 5 partitions, and I want the first 120 of them. Without Take or $top, there is no way for me to get only the first 120. I am forced to fetch 200 and then discard 80. Or am I not seeing something here?

Comment: Ah, I just found a pertinent line (again from the above link): "Note that the $top query option in the case where results are paginated specifies the maximum number of results per page, not the maximum number of results in the whole response set." So I guess this is telling me that there never was any server-side Take in the way that I understood it (or perhaps there was before and it was deprecated there too). 

So, just to confirm, in my scenario in the previous comment, am I correct to understand that I should just fetch until I have enough and discard the ones I don't need?

Comment: Exactly - $top doesn't really exist. So fetching at the appropriate max-per-page granularity until you get the amount you want the best you can do.

Comment: Okay, I grudgingly accept your answer. :-) Seriously, though, it would be really useful to be able to specify a max number of entities to return, across whatever number of pages is required to get it. I hope you'll consider that for the future! Either way, thank you for your time here getting this sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little controversial but I'm going to add this as an answer ... it looks like it's been raised as a feature request only a number of weeks ago and it's now been added to the backlog ...

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/30985

You're not the only one who has the same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

When limit is under 1000 Azure max, use explicit limit, when limit is 1000+ calculate how many pages and stop when you reach the count, and then trim to precise count.

When a query found 5000 and your wanted limit is 1001 then maximum overhead would be 999 because you'll download 2000 items and cut off 999. When your limit is < 1000 you pull only 1 page with exact count of items (no ovearhaed).

You could in theory do sophisticated maxPerPage calculation but it makes no sense, the HTTP is more costly on latency side, especially on mobile, so it is better to make fewer requests of biggest possible pages, than more requests of smaller pages.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsyncLimit<T>(string tableName, string filter, IEnumerable<string> select, int limit) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
{
    var tableClient = ...;
    var entities = new List<T>();
    var maxPerPage = limit < 1000 ? limit : 1000; // Azure page default is 1000 and it's max
    var pages = tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter, maxPerPage, select).AsPages();
    var currentPage = 1;

    await foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        entities.AddRange(page.Values);
        if (currentPage == GetPageCount(limit))
            break; //stop "downloading" pages
        currentPage++;
    }
    return entities.Take(limit); //cut off the excess when more than 1 page
}


private int GetPageCount(int limit)
{
    int pageSize = 1000; // Azure page default is 1000 and it's max
    int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)limit / pageSize);
    return pageCount;
}
```